# Type cast for inner HashMap to Map

Tags: java, casting, hashmap

Can I typecast a complex structure like HashMap<String,List<HashMap<String,String>>> to Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>> ?

Comment: probably easy way would be iterating it

Comment: Can you change the data at the source? Avoid the `List<HashMap<...>>` to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend stream the outer and inner map and then assign to parent reference `Map`

```
 Map<String,List<hMap<String,String>>> res = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    entry->entry.getValue().stream().map(HashMap::new).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

A `List<HashMap<String,String>>` is not a `List<Map<String,String>>`. You can pretend and use the raw type at your own risk:

```
HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String,String>>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>> cast = (Map) map;
```

You'll get a warning for unchecked assignment, because you can then do this:

```
String key = "";
cast.put(key, Collections.singletonList(new TreeMap<>())); // Not a HashMap
HashMap<String, String> inserted = map.get(key).get(0);
```

This compiles with no warning but will throw a `ClassCastException`.